# Locks when adding a column to a table and to a view

Tags: database, postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.1

Suppose I have this *foo* table in a PostgreSQL 9.1 database:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  bar integer,
  flg_deleted boolean
);
```

Along with this *vwfoo* view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwfoo AS
  SELECT bar
  FROM foo
  WHERE flg_deleted = false;
```

Also assume I have an application running a couple of short-lived transactions per second, using *vwfoo*.

Now, I want to add a column *baz* to *foo* and I want *baz* to be in *vwfoo* too. But, of course, I don't want my application to get any errors because of those changes.

If I execute the following steps (in a single transaction) to perform the desired change:

1. Drop *vwfoo*.
2. Add column *baz* to *foo*.
3. Create *vwfoo* again (now including *baz*).

Do I get the desired behavior (no errors in the application)?

Will there be an exclusive lock being held on *vwfoo* during the whole transaction (that's what I want)?

Is it possible that any transaction will try to use the view between steps 1 and 3 and then fail (instead of just blocking, waiting for a lock)?

Does the "identity" of *vwfoo* change when it's recreated? In other words: is it possible that any transaction will try to use the view between steps 1 and 3, block, resume after step 3 and then fail because the view was recreated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test suggests that this will cause problems with your application. To recreate, create two connections (`A` and `B`), then run:

```
A: BEGIN;
A: DROP VIEW vwfoo;
B: SELECT * FROM vwfoo;
(B blocks… )
A: CREATE VIEW vwfoo AS SELECT * FROM foo;
A: COMMIT;
(B yields:
    ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 326418
    LINE 1: SELECT * FROM vwfoo
)
```

Instead, you should do this kind of atomic swapping by renaming the views:

```
A: CREATE VIEW vwfoo_new AS SELECT * FROM foo;
A: BEGIN;
A: ALTER VIEW vwfoo RENAME TO vwfoo_old;
B: SELECT * FROM vwfoo;
(B blocks…)
A: ALTER VIEW vwfoo_new RENAME TO vwfoo;
A: COMMIT;
(B completes as expected)
A: DROP TABLE vwfoo_old;
```

This will work as expected (and you won't need to run a (comparatively) expensive `DROP TABLE` inside the transaction!)

**Edit**: You can use the same strategy to solve your "real" problem, too:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar_new TEXT;
UPDATE foo SET bar_new = bar;
CREATE VIEW vwfoo_new AS SELECT bar_new AS bar FROM foo;
… do the view switcheroo …
DROP VIEW vwfoo_old;
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE foo RENAME bar TO bar_old;
ALTER TABLE foo RENAME bar_new TO bar;
COMMIT;
ALTER TABLE foo DROP COLUMN bar_old;
```

The view referencing `bar_new` will be correctly updated, too:

```
# \d vwfoo
View definition:
 SELECT foo.a
   FROM foo
  WHERE foo.b = false;
# ALTER foo RENAME a TO new_a;
ALTER TABLE
# \d vwfoo
View definition:
 SELECT foo.newa AS a
   FROM foo
  WHERE foo.b = false;
```

Comment: Thank you. Although this is not the answer I expected, it is the answer to the question I've posted. :)
Unfortunately, my reality is a little more complex: I also need to change the type of "foo.bar" (which is actually VARCHAR(256)) to TEXT.

Comment: Ah, ok! Well, you can use the same strategy (along with `ALTER TABLE … RENAME …`) to do that, too :) It will involve a potentially expensive copy then `DROP COLUMN`, but you will have zero downtime!

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answer. Performing that copy is not an option for us, so our DBA has decided to increase the size of the VARCHAR column directly in `pg_attribute`.
To avoid future problems, I have decided to stop using views, since their convenience is not enough to make up for the problems they cause.
Again, thank you very much. :)